# we face error DevTools failed to load SourceMap

Tags: javascript

[this image is showing where we find warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkXc4.jpg)

i want to know how to remove this warning from JavaScript running ..please help
console.log('hello for java world');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Developer Tools, go to "Settings" for Developer Tools, then disable JavaScript Sourcemaps under the "Sources" settings.